# Indicator light for circuit powered off

Tags: logic-gates

The background is 
Off road motorcycle Radiator fan, temp controlled circuit is powered when key on power is present.
User wants a manual switch to kill the circuit...thats easy enough.
A Power on indicator light would be easy to add, but not what i want..

I want to give him a "Power off" indicator light so he can be warned his manual switch is in the off position.
I think what I need to build in order to make that work is a not logic gate..
A: Do I have that right?
B: If a not logic gate is what I need, what would be the "better" way to build a not logic gate used in a 12-14VDC system, subjected to vibrations, 45-120 deg F
C: Indicator light to be used is an LED

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Just use a changeover power-kill switch with the pole connected to power and the "new" contact connected to the lamp. Or better still ensure that if the temperature is high it sounds a buzzer.

Comment: A logic Inverter is a basic part that can drive a HB LED directly with 1K series for low current draw. Using a NAND gate can enable it with ignition.

Comment: True Tony, but logic gates and dirt bikes don't exactly mix.

Comment: Tony, thanks for the response, but do tell... Why would a basic logic circuity be not advisable for a dirt bike?
You do know modern off road bikes have , relays, Engine control units, sensors, latching relays, other computers, ect ect..Many electronics just like what would go into a basic logic circuit.
What is your concern here?

Thanks

Comment: Andy, thanks but from some quick google searches https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=changeover+power-kill+switch&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8 

Such a switch is way to bulky for the needed location.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You just need a SPDT (single pole, double throw) switch. The 12V power connects to the single common pole. One throw goes to the fan, the other to the warning light.

But I have to say that this sounds like a very bad idea, unless small engine repair is your favorite activity.

Comment: Small engine repair? 
I think you greatly misunderstand>> But in any case thanks for the response, but no I dont think that would work..
Your plan would give me a circuit ON indicator light ... That is not what we need.

Comment: No, you would get a "fan off" indicator. The switch would allow power to go to **either** the fan or the lamp and no current would go to the fan when it is disabled. However, based on your comments it looks like you left a lot of important information out of your question, such as connections to "temp sensor" and "temp controller". Oh well, GIGO.

Comment: Thanks, hard to include what info is required when you dont know what info is needed.

And yes I see what you meant now... I read double throw and my mind inserted double pole.

Yes SPDT might just do what I need, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another option.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjFh1o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Installing the LED across the fan enable switch will cause it to light if the FAN is disabled.*

This circuit relies on the LED current being low enough that it won't turn the fan. The LED will probably draw < 50 mA whereas the fan would require in the region of an amp to run so it should be fine.

Comment: Hmmm, that looks like it might work...
Need to think about it a bit...not sure what that low wattage to the fan circuit will do in second order effects..Doing it this way would also put that low wattage to the temp sensor, the temp controller and the fan motor itself.